# Adding a body class

Tags: php, wordpress

```
add_filter('body_class','cp_new_body_classes');
function cp_new_body_classes($classes) {
    if( !is_page_template() ) {
        $classes[] = 'reg-page';
    return $classes;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to append the class of `reg-page` to pages that are not page templates. For the pages that *are* page templates, I just want to leave the default WordPress classes. When trying the code above, the class of `reg-page` gets added like I want to pages which are not page templates but the other pages (which *are* page templates) get left with no classes at all. How can I fix this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, if the given URL does not correspond to a page, nothing is returned by the function. WordPress is handing you the classes that it has already evaluated and, by returning `null`, you tell it to forget about all of those. To fix: `return $classes` even if the condition fails.

```
add_filter('body_class','cp_new_body_classes');
function cp_new_body_classes($classes) {
    if( !is_page_template() )
        $classes[] = 'reg-page';

    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, just a quick question. I'm trying to add "or is not the home page" like this: `if( !is_page_template() || !is_home() )` but the `reg-page` class gets added to every page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want `reg-page` to be displayed on all parts of the site but pages and the home? That should work. `if ( !( is_page_template() || is_home() ) )` Am I understanding your intention correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Thank you. I didn't know that I had to put the exclamation mark outside.